# How do I install libleveldb-dev on windows for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, leveldb

How to install `libleveldb-dev (leveldb development libraries)` on windows? I need this to be downloaded so I can install plyvel. Thank you in advance I hope someone is familiar with this process.

The way to install this on Linux is :

`sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev`

But I need to install this on windows. Is there a similar easy way to do this in the windows command prompt? Related Link: https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#build-and-install-plyvel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answering for the next ones, there is a version of plyver just for windows that doesnt require all this suffering. just try: "pip install plyvel-win32" if you have the visual libraries should work.